# Any way to exploit relations between examples in dataset?

Tags: classification, graph-theory

Suppose I have a dataset with k examples:

`id1, feature1, feature2 .. featuren
...
idk, feature1, feature2 .. featuren`

For which I can label a training set and feed it to some classification algorithm, getting predictions.

Suppose my examples are also vertices in a sparse undirected graph. 
Is this possible to come up with some reasonable model that ensures predictions for neighbouring vertices tend to be the same?

Comment: Have you looked at the k nearest neighbors method?

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat Yes, thank you I've been thinking about it, though never gave it a try. How do I incorporate graph distance into a euclidean (or any other mertic) in the feature space?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to feed extra information about the examples to the classifier, you add this information as a feature. In your case, you would add some notion of the position of the example in the graph as a feature, so that examples that are close together have close values.

Comment: Yes this is probably the way to go.
But I seriously lack options here. I can think of some graph visualization technique mapping vertices into a [probably multidimensional] plane. But for my graph [and I should have mentioned that], there could be connected components as small as just two vertices yet with really informative edge between them. So, even I map the entire graph on a plane, I'd hardly grasp any correlations unless I use an extremely complex model and overfit terribly.
Any other way to map the graph into a feature space?